# Insert into multiple Tables from CTE´s with Conditions, invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a working query and now I want to insert most of it´s data into some tables.

My problem is that I don´t know how to insert into multiple tables at the same time, use it together with CTE´s and the Conditionals.

works:

```
with join1 as (...),
with join2 as (...),
with join3 as (..),
with relevantData as (use the joins),
select * from relevantData r;
```

This returns everything I want to have.

Now I want to move the relevantData, depending on some conditions, into different tables.

I have tried:

```
 insert all
 when r.column1 is not null then
  insert into table1(Signature) values (r.column1,r.column5)
when r.column30 <> 'barney'
 insert into table2(Signature) values (r.column8,r.column10,r.column11)

with join1 as (...),
with join2 as (...),
with join3 as (..),
with relevantData as ()
select * from relevantData r;
```

I have put the insert all as the first line but then the last r.column in my values is always false. ie: when I remove "insert into table2..." then the r.column5 will not be recognized, when I add it again the r.column11 will not be recognized.
However, if I remove this insert stuff again and only select for r.column5 it will be shown.

The error is: ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier

Comment: You don't need the `with` on each line, only for the first CTE

Answer (score 1):

You write only one time `with` keyword when writing cte's and when you write `insert all` clause then you only write `into` keyword not `insert into` like you did. Syntax goes:

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN CONDITION_1 THEN 
     INTO YOUR_TABLE_1 (COLUMN_LIST) VALUES (VALUE_LIST)
WHEN CONDITION_2 THEN 
     INTO YOUR_TABL_2 (COLUMN_LIST) VALUES (VALUE_LIST)
    ...
WITH CTE_1 AS (      
             SELECT STATEMENT
            ),
     CTE_2 AS(
             SELECT STATEMENT
            )...
     SELECT STATEMENT
```

Comment: Thank´s. I have changed my query and I still get the "invalid identifier" error on the last column of the value List.

Comment: Number of (column_list) has to be equal to number of (value_list). In your example you wrote `table2(Signature) values (r.column8,r.column10,r.column11)` and this will raise an error because you stated 1 column from table2 `table2(Signature)`  and 3 column values from cte `(r.column8,r.column10,r.column11)`